# Excel Listbox appearing on other hidden sheets

Tags: excel, vba

The excel file I'm working on have around 20-30 sheets. And then it has a cover page where I've added several button to jump to different hidden charts sheets. on the same page I'm making a listbox of all the chart sheets name to select from to print. The problem is that list box now keeps appearing to all the hidden chart whenever I click on the buttons to jump to certain chart. Not sure what's happening and how to stop the list box appearing on the hidden charts. I'm pretty new to Excel VBA, I'd appreciate some guidance here.

```
Sub MSChartBP01()
'
' MSChartBP01 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("MS_StrategyBP01").Visible = True
    Sheets("MS_StrategyBP01").Select
End Sub
```

P.S. It is only happening to the hidden chart. Unhidden charts are fine. The code I've used to hide the chart again is:

```
Sub GoBacktoMS()
'
' GoBacktoMS Macro
'

'
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Sheets("Reporting").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code for your listbox macro?

Comment: The listbox is in a User Form?  When do you set the visible for the sheet back to False?  I feel like we need to see more code on how you are toggling the Worksheets Visible and not Visible.  Is the Listbox always there like a Nav bar ("nonmodal")?  Need some more info and specifics . . . .

Comment: @BruceWayne I don't have any code for the list bos, it's just being populated using the property listfillrange section, thats it. I have a code to move selected items from one listbox to another in the same sheet for a button

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code No the list box is on a another sheet in the same workbook as those charts. I have a go back button setup on the chart which is just bringing me to the cover page and hiding the chart again.

Comment: @Ema189 perhaps we need to see the code relevant to the listbox if it is moving from one sheet to a hidden sheet with a chart on it.  I don't like to use activesheet but it might be better that selectedsheets in this instance, I am guessing you have multiple workbooks open?  You could use Thisworkbook.Activesheet (implies the workbook where the code is located and running from, and a single sheet that is currently active, presumably a hidden chart sheet) - I moved your added code to your question (you can modify it and provide more detail as it is not an answer, I would suggest deleting Ans)

Comment: Ema, Stack Overflow is not a typical forum, it's a Q&A site. All information relevant to your question needs to be *in the question* - don't post it in the "Answer" box. In order to add content to the question, use the [edit] link below the question.